# How to disable execution of arguments to a command sudo

Tags: sudo

How to disable execution of arguments to a command sudo.
My sudoers.d/test, dont' work. I need to disable the argument -i.

```
test ALL = (ALL:ALL) ALL, !/usr/bin/sudo [!-]*
```

Comment: It is possible with sudo regular expressions. Unfortunately in Ubuntu 23.04 and above.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer at the Unix & Linux regarding same question.

[Link to answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419074/551216) Credit to user [Tom Klino](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/30590/tom-klino)

Copy paste from said link:
For your original question, you will need to exclude `/bin/bash` (or whatever is defined as the user's shell in `/etc/passwd`), like so:

```
tomk ALL= ALL,!/bin/su,!/bin/bash
```

**However(!!!)**, as stated already in the comments to your question, even though this will deny the user from running `sudo -s` or `sudo -i`, **it will not really prevent him/her from getting an interactive shell as root.**

From `man sudoers`:

> Limitations of the ‘!’ operator

> It is generally not effective to “subtract” commands from ALL using the ‘!’ operator.  A user can trivially circumvent this by copying the desired command to a different name and then executing that.
> For example:

> ```
> bill    ALL = ALL, !SU, !SHELLS
> ```

> Doesn't really prevent bill from running the commands listed in SU or SHELLS since he can simply copy those commands to a different name, or use a shell escape from an editor or other program.  There‐
> fore, these kind of restrictions should be considered advisory at best (and reinforced by policy).

> In general, if a user has sudo ALL there is nothing to prevent them from creating their own program that gives them a root shell (or making their own copy of a shell) regardless of any ‘!’ elements in
> the user specification.